# Problema com Rotas Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-rotas

Eu organizei meus Controllers por pastas:
**Ex:Painel/Concessesionaria/Marcas -> CarrosController.php**

Na Rota tentei informar assim

```
Route::get('Painel\Concessesionaria\Marcas', ['as' => 'marcas', function () {

Route::get('marcas', 'MarcasController@index');
Route::post('marcas/view', 'MarcasController@view');
Route::post('marcas/add', 'MarcasController@add');
Route::post('marcas/delete', 'MarcasController@delete');
Route::post('marcas/edit', 'MarcasController@edit');
Route::post('marcas/update', 'MarcasController@update');

}]);
```

Mas está trazendo o seguinte erro *localhost:8000/locais*

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Comment: Preciso saber em qual pasta você colocou esse Painel/Concessionárias? Dentro de App/Http/Controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rota **locais** que vc acessou não está registrada, tente fazer isso e acessar **localhost:8000/marcas**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'marcas'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'Painel\Concessesionaria\Marcas\MarcasController@index');
    Route::post('/view', 'Painel\Concessesionaria\Marcas\MarcasController@view');
    Route::post('/add', 'Painel\Concessesionaria\Marcas\MarcasController@add');
    Route::post('/delete', 'Painel\Concessesionaria\Marcas\MarcasController@delete');
    Route::post('/edit', 'Painel\Concessesionaria\Marcas\MarcasController@edit');
    Route::post('/update', 'Painel\Concessesionaria\Marcas\MarcasController@update');

});
```

Comment: Deu certo era isso mesmo Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro parâmetro que você está passando para o método get não é a pasta dos seus controllers, vc deve passar como primeiro parâmetro p link da sua rota. Por esse motivo que está retornando este erro.

Altere assim em cada rota:

```
Route::get('marcas', 'Painel\Concessesionaria\Marcas\MarcasController@index');
```

Comment: Era como o Raylan postou logo abaixo minhas rotas não estavam registradas